# PHP Не работает проверка, через БД

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp, проверка

**Доброго времени суток. Почему не работает следующая проверка в PHP & MySQL?**
**Если что, использую RedBeanPHP** 
Вот сам код проверки:

```
if (isset($bugs['done']) == "false") {
        echo "<span class='badge badge-danger ml-2'>Не решена</span>";
    } 
    elseif (isset($bugs['done']) == "true") {
        echo "<span class='badge badge-success ml-2'>Решена</span>";
    }
```

Вывод : Не решена **(Хотя в Базе Данных в столбце `done` стоит True)**

Связь с базой данной есть, все выводит. В самой БД, есть столбец с названием `done`. По умолчанию он устанавливается `false`
В чем проблема? Пробовал разные варианты, через `0` и `1`, почему так происходит?

Comment: Просто, кто-то, не читает документации и смотрит, всякую лажу - которую тулят на видео уроках.

Comment: @And , ну разумеется куда лучше вставить своё "Я", вместо того, что бы просто помочь)

Comment: Дело в том, что вы не понимаете, как работают типы данных - это говорит о том, что вы даже не открывали доку, по языку, а только просто на свои усмотрения и фантазии ищите скрипты. Тут даже и ежу понятно, что `boolean !== string`. - это условие всегда будет `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас некорректное условие, вы сравниваете [isset()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php), которое возвращает булевое значение, с не пустой строкой. В итоге первое условие всегда истина при заданном значении для ключа 'done' и ложное только в том случае, если ключ не существует в массиве или его значение `null`, но в таком случае оба условия ложные. Попробуйте так:

```
if(isset($bugs['done'])) {
    echo ($bugs['done'] == 'false') ? "<span class='badge badge-danger ml-2'>Не решена</span>" : "<span class='badge badge-success ml-2'>Решена</span>";
}
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо большое! Такой вопрос еще, как лучше осуществлять такие проверки?